# How can I insert streaming video from specific URL to my Android application?

Tags: android, video, stream, live

I make a project for my Engineer's Thesis "Control a mobile object using Android application" and I want to put on my vehicle camera and streaming video on HTTP server by Rasberry Pi and catch this video to my application.

For that moment I would like to write a simple application, which could capture video from this URL -> http://www.ustream.tv/channel/DCRYzgGpfc5 (this is stream video from Sony Action Cam) I would like to achieve exactly this effect: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVB6W.jpg)

So, which video components should I use to this goal? I'll just mention that I'm using Android Studio. Maybe you know some tutorial about this?

Comment: @Gueg and Ouail Bellal thanks you for trying, but both components I mean that neither MediaPlayer were useless to my purpose, because both support only video format file .mp4 and .3gp while I stream video as .MPJG.

So, for posterity :) or in case someone had a similar problem on this site https://github.com/dydwo92/Android-Simple-MjpegViewer is app, which deal with .MPJG enough in MainActivity.java change link to our own and compile project. In my case II just copied it to my app and added what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), it can stream online videos from a local path or from an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some libraries 
for example : 
[JiaoZiVideoPlayer](https://github.com/lipangit/JiaoZiVideoPlayer)